# WEBVR - Force cardboard view

Tags: virtual-reality, webvr, google-vr

is it possible to start the cardboard view automaticly when the device is able to do this? I am using vrview in a webpage.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

No, by design. Users must be in control of their experience.  requestPresent() can only be called in response to a user gesture.

https://immersive-web.github.io/webvr/spec/1.1/#interface-vrdisplay

Promise requestPresent(sequence layers
);

If the user is in VR mode and traverses a link, the new page will start in VR mode if the browser supports this.